# Not recognized as a command - bash

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that takes in a set of arguments, and based off those we do different things. so in this case I am trying to say:

```
./acorn.sh aisiscore install
```

But it goes to my error message stating that the first argument is not reconized and that i should use aisiscore or assets. I checked the spelling and I am correct, am I not checking the arguments properly?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function checkCoreArgument(){
  if [[ $1 == 'aisiscore' ]]
  then
    checkAisisArguments
  elif [[ $1 == 'assets' || $1 == 'asset' ]]
  then
    checkAssetsArguments
  else
    echo "$1 is not recognized. Please try aisiscore or assets"
  fi
}

function checkAisisArguments(){
  if [[ $2 == 'install' ]]
  then
    installAisisCore
  elif [[ $2 == 'update' ]]
  then
    updateAisisCore
  elif [[ $2 == 'components' ]]
  then
    callCompomnentsCheck
  else
    echo "$2 is not recognized. Please try install or update."
  fi
}

function checkAssetsArguments(){
  if [[ $2 == 'install' ]]
  then
    installAssets
  elif [[ $2 == 'update' ]]
  then
    updateAisisCore
  else
    echo "$2 is not recognized. Please use install or update."
  fi
}

function installAisisCore(){
  cd scripts/install/
  chmod +x InstallAisisCore.sh
  sudo InstallAisisCore.sh
}

function updateAisisCore(){
  cd scripts/update/
  chmod +x UpdateAisisCore.sh
  sudo UpdateAisisCore.sh
}

function installAssets(){
  cd scripts/install/
  chmod +x InstallAssets.sh
  sudo InstallAssets.sh
}

function updateAisisCore(){
  cd scripts/update/
  chmod +x UpdateAssets.sh
  sudo UpdateAssets.sh
}

function callCompomnentsCheck(){
  cd scripts/install
  chmod +x InstallComponents.sh
  sudo ./InstallComponents.sh
}

###### =============================== [ Application run ] =============== ######

checkCoreArgument #run the app!
```

It's top down so it's easier to read.

Comment: Suggestion: use a `while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]` loop with a `case` statement and a `shift` for each case to loop through all the arguments, setting variables as you go to keep track of which tasks should be performed (and any other data you need from the arguments). Then put the code that actually performs the task inside of `if` blocks controlled by the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an expansion of John Kugelman's answer

- you don't need both the `function` keyword and the `()` parentheses
- there is a lot of cut'n'paste code that can be "parameterized"

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function checkArgs {
  case $1 in 
    aisiscore) 
      case $2 in
        install)    install "AisisCore"  ;;
        update)     update  "AisisCore"  ;;
        components) install "Components" ;;
        *) echo "$2 is not recognized. Please try install or update." ;;
      esac
      ;;
    assets | asset) 
      case $2 in 
        install) install "Assets" ;;
        update)  update  "Assets" ;;
        *) echo "$2 is not recognized. Please use install or update." ;;
      esac
      ;;
    *) echo "$1 is not recognized. Please try aisiscore or assets" ;;
  esac
}

function install    { cd scripts/install/ && callScript "Install${1}.sh"; }
function update     { cd scripts/update/  && callScript "Update${1}.sh"; }
function callScript { chmod +x "$1" && sudo "$1"; }

###### =============================== [ Application run ] =============== ######

checkArgs "$@"  #run the app!
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions get their own arguments in `$1`, `$2`, etc. If you want them to parse the script's arguments you have to pass them in.

```
checkCoreArgument "$@"
```

The same goes for the functions calling each other. Those function calls need to explicitly pass the arguments on.

```
function checkCoreArgument(){
  if [[ $1 == 'aisiscore' ]]
  then
    checkAisisArguments "$@"
  elif [[ $1 == 'assets' || $1 == 'asset' ]]
  then
    checkAssetsArguments "$@"
  else
    echo "$1 is not recognized. Please try aisiscore or assets"
  fi
}
```

Also, a small suggestion: you could use a `case` statement to make these checks a little nicer.

```
case $1 in
    aisiscore)    checkAisisArguments  "$@";;
    asset|assets) checkAssetsArguments "$@";;

    *) echo "$1 is not recognized. Please try aisiscore or assets" >&2;;
esac
```